Bootstrapping ridge regression in financial time series
I want to use ridge regression for a model of stock prediction, and want to use bootstrap to estimate the stability and variability of the coefficients. However, I have the concern that as financial time series are indexed by time, random sampling would inevitably lead, as I understand it, to data leakage. What's the correct procedure in this case? How can I appropriately use the bootstrap in this scenario? Any code in R is appreciated

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Look for versions of bootstrap for time series (e.g. block bootstrap).

Yes, thank you. I've read about moving block bootstrap, but I'm not finding too much information or how to do it in R anyways...
